# Random fail to load wordpress multisite on Chrome & Firefox browser

Tags: wordpress, shared-hosting, firefox, google-chrome, isp

I have a wp 3.5 multisite and sometimes the page fail to load..

I got this msg on chrome

1. Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to domain.x
2. Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.

on Firefox got this

1. Server not found
2. The connection has timed out

Update infos 2:

This a WordPress or hosting or isp issue?!

I scan my mulstiste wp site before a little moment with P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler):

**WordPress Plugin Profile Report:**

Report date: 24 January 2013

Theme name:

Pages browsed: 18

Avg. load time: 1.7010 sec

Number of plugins: 25

Plugin impact: 45.81% of load time

Avg. plugin time: 0.7792 sec

Avg. core time: 0.4346 sec

Avg. theme time: 0.4586 sec

Avg. mem usage: 25.86 MB

Avg. ticks: 17,257

Avg. db queries : 139.33

Margin of error : 0.0287 sec

**Plugin list:**

P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler) - 0.0088 sec - 1.12%

Bwp Google Xml Sitemaps - 0.0605 sec - 7.76%

Google Analytics For Wordpress - 0.0200 sec - 2.57%

Jw Player Plugin For Wordpress - 0.0241 sec - 3.09%

Google Analytics Social Engagement Tracking Code - 0.0005 sec - 0.06%

Multisite Toolbar Additions - 0.0039 sec - 0.50%

Multisite User Management - 0.0044 sec - 0.57%

My Gallery - 0.0188 sec - 2.41%

Nextgen Gallery - 0.0109 sec - 1.39%

NextScripts: SNAP Pro Upgrade Helper - 0.0060 sec - 0.77%

SEO Ultimate - 0.2213 sec - 28.40%

Social Networks Auto Poster Facebook Twitter G - 0.0767 sec - 9.84%

Use Google Libraries - 0.0140 sec - 1.80%

Watermark Hotlinked Images - 0.0007 sec - 0.09%

Wordpress Mu Domain Mapping - 0.2089 sec - 26.82%

WP Smush.it NextGEN Gallery Integration - 0.0004 sec - 0.05%

WP Smush.it - 0.0014 sec - 0.17%

Admin Locale - 0.0028 sec - 0.36%

Contact Form 7 - 0.0166 sec - 2.13%

Really Simple CAPTCHA - 0.0004 sec - 0.06%

Simple Ads Manager - 0.0068 sec - 0.88%

Top 10 - 0.0154 sec - 1.98%

Welcome Popup - 0.0278 sec - 3.57%

Wordpress Social Share Buttons - 0.0023 sec - 0.30%

WP-Filebase - 0.0258 sec - 3.32%

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this properly.  It could be a WordPress issue, an ISP issue or (most likely) a combination of the two.

Comment: @JCL1178 what information you want exactly to help me ? :)

Comment: Not sure. You need to be checking the server logs for errors related to this, monitor performance of both the web server and MySQL server, get memory usage reports, etc.  If you can narrow down the cause of the error to a certain sequence of actions or environment, that would help.

Comment: @JCL1178 i don't have any error_log in my root folder, on Resource Usage Overview of my cpanel show me this msg "Your site has been limited within the past 24 hours>CPU resources were limited for your site & Virtual memory resources were limited for your site" and my stas from last hour is this http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/152/resourceusageoverview.jpg/

Comment: The above explains why you are receiving connection errors.  Something in your server environment is off or something in your WordPress install is causing a load on the CPU and when that happens you will get errors (and the ISP will throw a limit on you).  You are just going to have to monitor the server and isolate the script or process that is out of control.

Comment: @JCL1178 i'm on shared-hosting in a reseller account. Also, if i reload the page again everything is ok, or not some times have to try to reload again(more of one time, max two times)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on the above discussion the issue is with your ISP/server environment.  Either it is under too heavy of an overall load (the reseller is overselling), is underpowered, or one of your plugins is rogue and causing the CPU to strain.

I would lean more towards the former as the cause of your problems.  When purchasing shared server space, you really have no idea how many other sites are on that server nor do you really know how robust that server is.  My guess is that moving to your own hosting on a VPS or to WordPress-specific hosting will resolve all of the issues.

Comment: Check my updated infos, Also, the only thing that i don't have, is that i haven't gone yet to vps server i don't know if a can manage it all by myself - applying operating system patches. :/

Comment: Wordpress Mu Domain Mapping - 0.2089 sec - 26.82% may be part of the problem.  I'm not saying you should run your own server, I'm saying you should consider better hosting.

Comment: the problem is stop when my host when he found spam account in server and disable it